# How to set size and amount of log files (stdout, stderr) in tomcat?

Tags: java, security, tomcat

I recently deployed a java app on my production server. In which I have installed **Tomcat version 8.5** and I have been having problems since the log files **stderr** and **stdout** grow in size exaggeratedly and therefore I lower the performance of the server or sometimes it is necessary to restart it since it does not respond. I would like to know how to configure these files so that they create only a certain **amount** with a specific **size**. I have tried configuring it through log4j it has given me error when integrating this same a tomcat. I have also configured certain parameters (for example: java.util.logging.FileHandler.limit = 1024) for logging in which the size and quantity are assigned but these do not apply to the configuration and therefore I continue to throw the server .

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5822763/how-can-i-roll-over-tomcat-5-5-stderr-and-stdout-files-when-they-get-too-large-b?rq=1

Comment: edit your question ...

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a production environment, a good practice is to use a process that works with small log files, and that creates a new one if the critical size has gone.

With log4j you can use a [RollingFileAppender](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/RollingFileAppender.html). See the minimal configuration :

```
<appender name="rolling.file.appender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="maxFileSize" value="50MB" />
    <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.base}/logs/myApplication.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<!-- Root Logger -->
<root>
    <priority value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="rolling.file.appender" />
</root>
```

Documentation: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: I am using property file I have set up exactly the same thing. The detail that still does not make me that functionality only creates the files but does not register the log (stdout, stderr). So I managed to detect that tomcat is still working with JULI and not using log4j as already configured for such use